# Fake documents to obtain Shenzhen Visit visa

Tags: tourist-visas

what are the consequences of producing Fake documents to obtain Shenzhen Visit visa from India. will there be any action taken by Embassy or simply reject the visa

Comment: Related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66613/coming-up-with-a-fake-travel-plan-to-apply-for-a-schengen-visa-will-i-get-caugh

Comment: If you know how to get fake documents in your country, you can be sure that the people tasked with verifying those same documents will know too and will spot them a mile off. If your plans for your future include visiting other countries (or maybe even working overseas) a deception / fraud record on your travel history will ruin those hopes.

Comment: [Shenzhen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shenzhen) or [Schengen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area)?

Comment: @phoog Oh, good catch. I didn't notice because visas are often an issue for people visiting Shenzhen on a trip to Hong Kong.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I know!  And people also often confuse the two names when posting here (or perhaps their autocorrect functions do that).  In the end, the question and the answers are general enough that it probably doesn't matter which visa is being sought.

Answer (score 7):

When the country you are applying to finds that the documents are fake, following things can happen.

- Visa application will be rejected for sure.
- You will be likeley banned for life or for a long period of time.
- You will have to declare this visa rejection for any similar countries, on which they won't be giving visas.
- You can be refereed to local law enforcement. According to Section 464 of IPC, you will be charged a criminal case.

Any number of things can happen. So, please don't do that. If you think you cannot get visa in current circumstances, get an expert in immigration law for advice.

Answer (score 4):

Just from the top of mind:

You could be refused a visa. You could be banned from that country. You could be refused visas and banned from *other* countries. You could be arrested in your country and go to prison.

Comment: You could also be arrested in the _other_ country and go to prison.  In this case, said other country would be China, which is not generally known for the hospitality it shows to prisoners.