# Applying for Schengen visa, what does 'member state of first entry' mean?

Tags: schengen, terminology, tourist-visas

I was filling in the forms to apply for a Schengen visa and I do not understand how to fill in my Member state of first entry. What does it mean exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which country visa should i apply to? - Schengen](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48538/which-country-visa-should-i-apply-to-schengen)

Comment: @chx this question is tangentially related to that question. It's certainly not a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

The Schengen zone has (as of 3 March 2016) 26 member states.  And despite Schengen being a single zone for visa and movement purposes, the responsibility for approving Schengen visas is factored out to each of the 26 members.

**Member state of first entry ... What does it mean exactly?**

A person arrives into the Schengen zone from outside of the zone, like China or Egypt and so on.  And the first time you touch down (or otherwise cross a border into a member state), it is your first entry.

At the risk of being pedantic, I can add that you can determine this by examining your itinerary and identifying the first place you will arrive in that requires a Schengen visa.

Also note that the the member of your first entry may or may not be the member who should process your application.  See [Which country visa should i apply to? - Schengen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48538/which-country-visa-should-i-apply-to-schengen)

Comment: Yes, true, I, as always used KLM/AMS, on Hungarian visa I wrote Hungary, and the lady explained this to me that Netherlands will be yourfirst state of entry, and Border Control wukk be processed there.

Comment: With the exception of "weird" multi-layover itineraries such as Toronto -  Reykjavik - London - Prague, where your first touch-down in a Schengen country is not an entry.